# Windows 7 as VM inside ubuntu 13.10 good for gaming

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, gaming

So i have wanted to do this for quite some time now, but after using Linux Mint Olivia (15), which has given me WiFi & sound issues, I am sceptical but still eager to try this out, although I dont really want to format if it is not reliable

So I have been wondering, I have downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 64bit, is it  better to run Windows 7 as a virtual machine and do gaming like that or on a dual boot

Keep in mind, I am a Linux newbie but an eagertistical learner of Linux, currently configuring VPS servers for pulbic use aswel, so I would like to configure and test out inside VMware W7

**Update**

Sorry I forgot to mention, I get BSOD often, reason - ntfs.sys, thus my HDD is failing, however I have read/discovered that Linux just ignores that block and carries on where Windows does not, instead giving bsod, I ave also been told that W7 runs marginally faster in a VM...

I need opinions and facts, dualboot/VM W7 in Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: "Eagertistical" ... I like that.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your criteria for success:

If you're looking for gaming performance, then dual boot should be the better option.

If you're looking for convenience only, then vm.

More related questions:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/133845/deciding-between-virtual-machine-or-dual-boot-setup

https://askubuntu.com/questions/119265/can-i-use-virtualbox-as-a-sandbox-for-12-04/119280#119280

Comment: check update posted